# NetBeans & JSP: How to correct / avoid html parsing errors?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, netbeans

Reviewing some legacy source files, I came across a jsp with the following code:

```jsp
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" 
        language="java"
        contentType="text/html" %>

<%-- omitted... --%>

<c:set var="abtNummer" value="0"/>

<%-- omitted... --%>

<c:set var="abtNummer" value="${abtNummer + 1}"/>
<a href="#abt${abtNummer}"> ${section}</a>

<%-- omitted... --%>
```

NetBeans is reporting the following parsing error for the `<a href...>` element:

```
Bad value "#abt  " for attribute "href" on element "a": DOUBLE_WHITESPACE in
FRAGMENT.
Syntax of IRI reference:
Any URL. For example: '/hello', '#canvas', or 'http://example.org/'. Characters
should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as '%20'.
```

I would say that NetBeans is trying to resolve `${abtNummer}` during the live-parsing?

Both `abtNummer` and `section` have valid runtime values, and in fact, the code works. After a few hours reading JSP and EL specs (I'm not a Java EE expert), and searching for NetBeans bugs, I have convinced myself that the line is completely legal, and that it doesn't need any kind of improvement.

I was about to file a bug against NetBeans, but I am not sure that this is a bug: is there anything I have to add to this JSP to signal NetBeans not to validate dynamic content for these kind of attributes? Or am I just doing something wrong?

**Edit**:

I have filed a bug: [Wrong html parsing error when editing jsp fragment](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212497)

---

Tested with NetBeans 7.1 and 7.1.2.

Comment: Go ahead reporting this bug. In the meanwhile check Netbeans settings to turn off EL validation if this error bothers you. As I don't use Netbeans, I can't tell from top of head if this setting exist and if so where you can find it. At least, Eclipse has similar quirks with EL validation (but not particularly this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the reported bug, you can config this warning in `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints -> HTML Validator -> Attribute`:

[image: Config bad value parsing warning]